# Swift Protocol Delegate return nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

```
protocol testDelegate: class {
    func open(channel: String, vc: UIViewController)
}

class test: UIViewController{

    weak var delegate: testDelegate?
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if self.delegate != nil {
        print("hello")
        self.delegate?.openGroupChannel(channel: channel!, vc: self)

}
```

that is Class Test! protocol init in Test class as well

```
class calling:testDelegate{

override func viewDidLoad() {
        //blah blah       
    }   

func func open(channel: String, vc: UIViewController){
    print("calling")
}
```

This is calling class.

I want to call open func in calling class but it does not calling at all, 
even print("hello") in test class is not calling it keeps return nil therefore does not call calling function as well.

Comment: Have you set the delegate of test controller in calling controller ?

Comment: @NiravD i set like class calling:testDelegate like this

Comment: That was used to implement protocol what i'm asking is where you are setting the delegate ?

Comment: @NiravD i didnt set maybe that's why? but even test class delegate is nil so i don't know calling method is actullay working

Comment: so sad... even test class's delegate is nil!!! don't know why bb @NiravD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set your `calling` as delegate of `test` ViewController. 
In your `calling` class create object of `test` class before navigation and set `calling` class as delegate of your `test` class as

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if let testVc = segue.destinationViewController as? test {
    testVc .delegate = self
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.. Happy Coding!!

Comment: Because you not assigned any class as delgate of your test class.

Comment: You can set your calling class as delegate of your test class before navigating from call to test.